# MPAndroidChart how to move data set to position -1 after remove position on 0

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have problem with my algoritm. I delete position on 0, but my dataset ddint move like -1. Then i add a new Entry on position 25. Continuous this maked my project alway delete last entry and non stop adding the Entry in position 25.

Here is code:

```
private void addEntry() {
    data = mChart.getData();
    if (set1 == null) {
        set1 = createSet();
        data.addDataSet(set1);
    }
    int prog = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < prog; i++) {
        float val = (float) (Math.random() * 2);
        float high = (float) (Math.random() * 1) + 2f;
        float low = (float) (Math.random() * 1) + 2f;
        float open = (float) (Math.random() * 2) + 1f;
        float close = (float) (Math.random() * 2) + 1f;
        boolean even = i % 2 == 0;
        data.addEntry(new CandleEntry(25, val + high, val - low, even ? val + open : val - open,
                even ? val - close : val + close), 0);
        data.notifyDataChanged();
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(25);
        mChart.moveViewTo(data.getEntryCount() - 24, 2f, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
    }
}

private void removeLastEntry() {
    CandleData data = mChart.getData();
    if (data != null) {
        ICandleDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);
        if (set != null) {
            Entry e = set.getEntryForIndex(0);
            data.removeEntry(e, 0);
            data.notifyDataChanged();
            mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mChart.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataSet#getEntryForIndex(int index)` returns the entry that is first in the backing array of `Entry` which may or may not be the `Entry` with the minimum `x` value on the chart. From the [javadoc](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/DataSet.html):

> Returns the Entry object found at the given index (NOT xIndex) in the values array.

I suspect you actually want to use something like the following:

```
float xMin = dataSet.getXMin();
dataSet.remove(dataSet.getEntryForXPos(xMin);
```

See the javadoc [here](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/DataSet.html).

However, your use case is a little bit unusual. You want all the other entries to "move down", it would seem, when you remove the `Entry` with the minimum value. If you are only doing this infrequently, it may be easier to construct a new dataset when you do that. Please note that while adding `Entry` to the chart is easy, random access to `Entry` and removing them is not supported so well. See the following note in [the wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data)

> Please be aware that this library does not officially support drawing LineChart data from an Entry list not sorted by the x-position of the entries in ascending manner. Adding entries in an unsorted way may result in correct drawing, but may also lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Rodriquez I'm glad it helps! Good luck with your project!